# Is it possible to set two column values with one being `allow_commit_timestamp`?

Tags: sql, google-cloud-spanner

```
UPDATE Performances 
SET NOTE = "random text", 
    LastUpdated = PENDING_COMMIT_TIMESTAMP()
WHERE SingerId = 1 
  AND VenueId = 2 
  AND EventDate = "2015-10-21"
```

Is the best practice is to have `batchUpdate` and send two queries with the last one being `PENDING_COMMIT_TIMESTAMP`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, and in most cases also the preferable way to do it. Splitting it into two statements and executing these using a `batchUpdate` call is not recommended.

The only exception would be if you intend to read from the commit timestamp column during the same transaction. Setting the `LastUpdated` column to `PENDING_COMMIT_TIMESTAMP()` will [make the column unreadable for the remainder of the transaction](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/dml-tasks#writing_commit_timestamps), so in that case it could make sense to set the `LastUpdated` value at a later moment. Note however that it does not make sense to do so using a single `batchUpdate`, as you would have no chance of actually trying to read from the table between the two update statements.